# C++ Inheritance: two subclasses of the same class as member variables

Tags: c++, inheritance, include

## C++ inheritance and #include collisions

#### Summary

In one file, I include two subclasses of the same class. Since each subclass imports the header file of the base class, this imports their base class twice, and causes an error:

```
build/classes/Market.h:8:7: error: redefinition of 'Market'
class Market {
      ^
build/classes/Market.h:8:7: note: previous definition is here
class Market {
```

---

#### Class Definitions

I have a base class, `Market` in `Market.h`:

```
class Market {

public:
    // ...

private:
    // ...
};
```

The classes `CerealMarket` and `CheeseMarket` are subclasses of this class:

In `CerealMarket.h`:

```
#include "Market.h"

class CerealMarket: public Market {

public:
    // ...

private:
    // ...
};
```

And in `CheeseMarket.h`:

```
#include "Market.h"

class CheeseMarket: public Market {

public:
    // ...

private:
    // ...
};
```

Finally, there is a class `CommodityExchange` which stores one instance of a `CerealMarket` and one instance of a `CheeseMarket`:

```
#include "CerealMarket.h"
#include "CheeseMarket.h"

class CommodityExchange {

public:
    // ...

private:
    const CheeseMarket cheeseMarket;
    const CerealMarket cerealMarket;
};
```

However, this `#include`s `Market.h` twice. Is it possible to have this structure of class inheritance without having the compiler think there is a duplicate definition of `Market`?

I'm building with the following command:
`g++ -Wall -Werror -pedantic -O1 main.cpp CommodityExchange.cpp Market.cpp CerealMarket.cpp CheeseMarket.cpp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Market.h`, just put `#pragma once` on the very top of the file.
Alternatively you can also use guards:

```
#ifndef MARKET_H
#define MARKET_H

/* your class declaration */

#endif // MARKET_H
```

This is common practice to avoid double inclusion of headers in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You need include guards:

```
#ifndef MARKET_H
#define MARKET_H

 // your code

#endif
```

These prevents compiler from including twice one file.